# how to change column type to autonumber

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I tried to change column type to autonumber, i changed some columns to text by this query :

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TEXT(500)
```

It's working, but i can't change the column type to autonumber by query,
so i tried to write code to change the column type :

```
Dim statement As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [" & TableName & "]")
Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(statement, con)
Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
Dim schema As DataTable = New DataTable
adapter.FillSchema(schema, SchemaType.Source)
Dim c As DataColumn = schema.Columns(schema.Columns.Count - 1) //Last Column
adapter.Dispose()
command.Dispose()
schema.Dispose()
```

So the column is `C` (DataColumn), i don't know what to do next...
(how can i change this column type to autonumber(C# / VB.net))

Comment: `c#` tag is irrelevant here. Removed

Comment: @SonerGönül i think that c# tag is not redundant here. if someone answer contains c# code it's enough for me.

Comment: @GordThompson no, the column is empty

Comment: Are you talking about identity field column?

Comment: @DamienJoe Yes, if you don't understant what i'm trying to do read my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948611/how-to-change-column-type-to-autonumber#comment29691187_19949705

Answer (score 0):

If a table in an Access database has existing records then you cannot convert an *existing* field to AutoNumber, even if that field is empty:

> Once you enter data in a table, you can't change the data type of any field to AutoNumber, even if you haven't yet added data to that field.

[image: noAuto.png]

So, what you'll need to do is DROP the existing (empty) column and then add a new AutoNumber column with the same name

```csharp
cmd.CommandText =
        "ALTER TABLE myTable DROP COLUMN myID";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText =
        "ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN myID IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: thanks, but this code is creating new column and not changing the type of column, i can change the type by myself (manually) , but i got 200 tables so i have to change the type of the column by code.
i also can remove the column and save his name in string and then i can Re-create this column by query but i don't know how to create new column with autonumber type, i only succeed to change the type of any column to TEXT , so if there is any other way to change the column type to autonumber(not by query) let me know about it :).

Comment: @JC11 What you dont realize is that when you change it from the GUI, MS Access is doing something similar to the code above, it is not one line, it is many.  First, create the new column the way you want it but with a different name, then update the data, then rename the column, drop the old column and finally, set the starting increment number of the column to the greatest value +1